# How to add multpile blob files to filelist (to append in form data)

Tags: javascript

is there any way to add multiple blob images into fileList (to append in formData)?

---

this code upload only the last image.

```
var formData = new FormData();
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.list li > img');
images.forEach(function(image) {
                formData.append("files", b64toBlob(image.src));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append an array to formData with bracket notation:

```
images.forEach(function(image) {
    formData.append("files[]", b64toBlob(image.src));
});
```